# Vectorize a function for integral2

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I want to evaluate a double integral of the form \int_{-\infty}^a \int_{-infty}^b sum_{i,j}^K a_i*a_j*x^i*y^j*exp(-x^2 - y^2 + x*y)dx dy

where a_i and a_j are constants. Since the integral is linear, I can interchange summation and integration, but in this case I have to evaluate K^2 integrals and it takes too long. In that case I do the following:

```
for i = 1:K
   for j = 1:K
       fun = @(x,y) x.^i.*y.^j.*exp(-2.*(x.^2 + y.^2 - 2.*x.*y))
       part(i,j) = alpha(i)*alpha(j)*integral2(fun,-inf,a,-inf,b)
   end
end
```

It takes too long, so I want to evaluate only one integral, but I don't know how to vectorize sum_{i,j}^K a_i*a_j*x^i*y^j*exp(-x^2 - y^2 + x*y), namely, how to supply it to integral2. | would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: it's not possible to properly visualize the function you wrote in latex style. Please edit the question properly.

Comment: @fpe: Could you tell me whether I can write here in Latex style? I tried but it was not successful.

Comment: unlike other stackexchange forums, I believe that here on SO you cannot write in latex style.

Comment: @fpe:Unfortunately my reputation score is not high enough, so I cannot insert pictures. Without that I don't know how I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
I = [1:K]';
J = [1:K]';
funhandle = @(x,y)(sum(sum(...
repmat(alpha(I),1,K)...
.*repmat(alpha(J)',K,1)...
.*repmat(x.^I,1,K)...
.*repmat((y.^J)',K,1)))...
*exp(-x^2-y^2+x*y))
```

I think it does the sum you want correctly...

Comment: I tred to adopt your method but I didn't succed, since a function handle should accept arrays. The fastest solution which I have by now is `syms s1 s2
z = [s1 s2]*Oginv*[s1;s2];

f = (alpha(1)*(alpha(1) + 2*(alpha(2)*z + alpha(3)*z^2 + alpha(4)*z^3 + alpha(5)*z^4 + alpha(6)*z^5)) + ...
    alpha(2)*(alpha(2)*z^2 + 2*(alpha(3)*z^3 + alpha(4)*z^4 + alpha(5)*z^5 + alpha(6)*z^6)) + ...
    alpha(3)*(alpha(3)*z^4 + 2*(alpha(4)*z^5 + alpha(5)*z^6 + alpha(6)*z^7)) + ...
    alpha(4)*(alpha(4)*z^6 + 2*(alpha(5)*z^7 + alpha(6)*z^8))+...`

Comment: `alpha(5)*(alpha(5)*z^8 + 2*(alpha(6)*z^9)) +...
    alpha(6)*alpha(6)*z^10)*exp(-z/2);

fun  = matlabFunction(f);
cdf2 = integral2(fun,-inf,a,-inf,b);` However, it still takes one second...